# Is "netplan apply" required if I reboot after changing /etc/netplan/xxx-config.yaml file

Tags: linux, linux-networking, netplan

If I change the network device config in /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml and then reboot will it apply the changes, or must I explicitly do "netplan apply"?

(Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation it is not necessary to run `netplan apply` manually after a reboot:

> During early boot, the netplan “network renderer” runs which reads
> `/{lib,etc,run}/netplan/*.yaml` and writes configuration to `/run`  to  hand  off  control  of
> devices to the specified networking daemon.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/netplan.5.html